# Rendering faster the transparent areas in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

So, is there anyway to render faster the transparent areas of a 3D animation?
For example: my background is transparent and most of the image will be transparent, but for some reason Cycles takes minutes to render these transparent areas.

Comment: There is a commercial add-on that animates the render border. Maybe that will help. https://blendermarket.com/products/animated-render-border/

Answer (score 3):

Branched path tracing is significantly faster on empty background areas since it limits initial samples and instead gathers multiple subsamples: [What is branched path tracing and how is it useful?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3256/what-is-branched-path-tracing-and-how-is-it-useful)

Some effects such as depth of field or motion blur may need a lot of initial samples anyway though, so branched path may not always be faster. Additionally, it consumes quite a lot of extra memory when running on GPU, so it can easily put a scene over the edge of fitting in VRAM or not.