# Volumetric Scatter affected (Same file, different computers) CPU vs GPU

Tags: light, volumetrics

I've worked on a scene on my 2015 MacBook Pro and it looks great, but takes too long to render.

I bought an RTX 2080 for my PC and the volumetric scatter is barely visible.

Why is my RTX 2080 performing worse than my 4+ year old laptop and how can I get the volumetric scatter to show correctly?

**EDIT 1**

So I found one problem. For some reason all the light sources are reset to default values at `100w`.

Changing the values to the values I initially had set them to does not make a difference.

**HOWEVER**

Now when I switch to CPU rendering the image is displayed correctly.
But GPU rendering still renders incorrectly.

**EDIT 2**

I've narrowed it down to CPU vs GPU.
When rendered on the CPU it looks exactly as I expect, but on the GPU it doesn't look right.

Comment: The output result shouldn't depend on the hardware. In order to render on the GPU you need to select it has compute device in the preferences and select `GPU` as device in Cycle's render settings.

Comment: It is on GPU Compute, Feature Set: Supported.
Literally nothing is changed. The exact same file.

Comment: Make sure that you have the latest graphic drivers installed. If that doesn't fix it, please write a bug report and add a minimal working example project that shows CPU and GPU rendering with Cycles produce different results.

Comment: I'm suspecting that 2.8 does not even support RTX 2080 properly. I still need to do some testing before I write the bug report. Can you share the link to bug report?

Comment: The RTX 2080 is supported. Make sure you have the latest driver installed (https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx). In case this still happens with the latest driver, open Blender and go to *Help > Report a Bug*. Make sure to fill out all the information in the template.

Comment: Solved it......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by changing sampling integrator to `Branched Path Tracing`.

This is not needed when rendering on the CPU, but apparently required when rendering on the CPU.

I found the solution here: [Volumetric scatter shader does not show light focused through lens correctly](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97145/volumetric-scatter-shader-does-not-show-light-focused-through-lens-correctly)