# Volumetric (Gods rays) no light emmiting out (duplicate)

Tags: light, volumetrics

With the reference of this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110825/volume-gods-rays-are-not-well-defined) i can't get the rays out.

[image]

Below the eyes there is a point lamp and i want to make the light come from the eyes. Like god rays

No light pass

[image]

I have added a wire cube with volumetric setting but still no lights pop out. Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Volume nodes

[image]

Comment: I cannot help without seeing the material properties of the volumetric cube. Post the nodes?

Comment: @3pointedit i have attach the file plz go through it

Comment: @3pointedit plz check the nodes attach above

Comment: Black volume material doesn't work very well. Better to use world volume for the effect you are going for anyway I would think.

Comment: Use white as color on the volume scatter and give it a low value, start with 0.1

Comment: @cegaton white color to the cube or world setting

Comment: [Image](https://imgur.com/a/8nRNr0i). Turn the lamp way up (255). Turn the cube's emission to white and reduce the density (0.02), otherwise everything will be foggy. You may have to reposition the lamp and move it further away from the socket to make the beams more directional

Comment: @atek why did you write duplicate as part of the title?

Comment: @cegaton will im confuse what to write once i have written solved they commented now written duplicate got comment what to mention. I solved my problem tweaking.