# How to not render unnecessary tiles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, optimization

When rendering an image in cycles render, I find that lots of the time is spend rendering completely blank tiles, especially when I have high samples. Is there any way for blender to know when a tile does not have anything in it and skip rendering it? If not is there any add on that can help with this? Thank you for all your help. [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no automatic way.

Cycles render engine uses [path tracing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3256/what-is-branched-path-tracing-and-how-is-it-useful) to render a scene. In order to calculate whether there are additional objects that might cast light/shadow in a scene, it has to calculate the whole scene based on the camera's view.

The only method for Cycles to get that information before the final render would be through pre-processing, which in the end would take more time than rendering empty tiles.

However, you can restrict the render area by using the Render Border feature. 
Hit <kbd>0</kbd> on the Numpad to enter Camera View, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and draw a box around the area you want to have in your final result.

[image: restrict render]

Now only the selected area gets rendered and the result gets resized to the final image's size.

[image]