# How can I remove a reflection onto an object but keep the shadow?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I tried isolating the two objects via layers, but that removes the shadows as well:

[image]

When I don't isolate, I get these little single-pixel reflections on the image material for the background object:

[image]

See them?
They're annoying. Is there any way to remove them without removing the shadows?

[Blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5i33G9TR2piNTA2NjJ6MV9pdzA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Those single pixel reflections are commonly known as *Fireflies*. You might want to try removing them by enabling *No caustics* in *Render settings > Light Paths*, or by using the clamp options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those single pixel reflections are commonly known as *[fireflies](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2275/599)*.

Fireflies can often be removed by disabling [caustics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caustic_%28optics%29), as they are usually a result of an unlikely indirect sample of a lamp.

If you don't want or need caustics, then simply enable *No Caustics* in *Render settings > Light paths*.

### Clamping

If you want to keep caustics, you might try using the *Clamp* options in *Render settings > Sampling*.
The clamp options will ensure a sample does not return a higher value than the clamp value, but be aware that this can potentially affect highlights and other intentionally bright areas of the render.

To help avoid this, in 2.70 you can now clamp indirect samples (where fireflies are usually found) separately from direct samples.

---

Also see:

- [How to reduce fireflies in Cycles?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1703/599)
- [the *Reducing noise* section of the wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Reducing_Noise#Reducing_Noise).