# Bright pixels that appear on the model after rendering

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

[image]

I got this bright pixels, what is reason? , any one can help me for this

Comment: Those bright pixels are called fireflies you might find this links useful: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1703/how-to-reduce-fireflies-in-cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40040/fireflies-noise-on-glossy-material and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41803/why-do-fireflies-increase-with-number-of-samples-when-using-a-hdri-light-source and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/what-is-the-reason-cycles-creates-incorrectly-colored-firefly-artifact-pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These pixels are called fireflies. The solution is to increase the amount of samples. I would try at least 500:

[image]